# Posting or passing perl variables to next web page?

Tags: perl

How can I pass the variables from one perl webpage to the next, here is my example:

This is what I want passed from the first page, `$data[0]` and `$data[2]`

```
<a href="Month_entries.pl?month='$data[2]'&user='$data[0]' 
       style="text-decoration:none" 
       onclick="return popitup('Month_entries')">$busitotal2</a>
```

With it going to `Month_entries.pl` how to a call these variables in the new webpage(Month_entries)? what is this process called?

Comment: Yep, you don't mention if you use a framework or CGI or something.

Comment: Im using CGI just not sure how to set it up correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should make sure that you are constructing the URI you actually want.

- You probably don't want `'` characters in the data
- You problem should be protecting against XSS and broken data with [URI::Encode](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aEncode).

Then it comes down to getting data from the query string.

How you do this depends on how you server and Perl are communicating.

If you are using Plack (which is generally a good idea for modern Perl), then see the code in the synopsis for [Plack::Request](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aRequest):

```
my $app_or_middleware = sub {
    my $env = shift;
    my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
    my $path_info = $req->path_info;

    # Change 'query' to whatever you called your key in the query string
    my $query     = $req->param('query');

    my $res = $req->new_response(200);
    $res->finalize;
};
```

If you are using a framework (such as Web::Simple, Catalyst or Dancer) then it will probably provide its own interface.

If you are using CGI, and using the CGI module, you would:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $ query = $cgi->param('query')
```

Comment: I am using CGI but I'm sorry i don't fully understand how to pass the variable using it. Any advice?

Comment: I think i figured it out! my $query = new CGI; then my $user = $query->param('user'); worked in my case. Thank you!